# that of + (noun) structure

Tags: compounds

> The FRA has a compressive strenght over three times that of the vertebral body

Can someone explain the "that of the..." part? I couldn't understand what kind of structure it is.

Answer (score 2):

The *that* refers to *compressive strength*, so *three times that of the vertebral body* means "three times the compressive strength of the vertebral body".